# Why does it take minutes to initialize tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

I want to analyze the mnist dataset as a reference for other tasks. I want to use the Sequential model but the simple statement `model = Sequential()`  takes minutes to complete. A session to demonstrate this looks like this:

```
$ python 
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 11:38:51) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2022-07-25 16:21:43.123581: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
>>> import keras
>>> tf.__version__
'2.4.1'
>>> keras.__version__
'2.4.3'
>>> model = keras.Sequential()
2022-07-25 16:22:35.403458: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2022-07-25 16:22:35.405376: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2022-07-25 16:22:35.420936: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:22:35.421084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.425GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 5.81GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2022-07-25 16:22:35.421098: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2022-07-25 16:22:35.422331: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.422360: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.423530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.423698: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.424816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.425370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.427463: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-07-25 16:22:35.427602: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:22:35.427761: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:22:35.427846: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428102: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428694: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428782: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428876: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.425GHz coreCount: 30 deviceMemorySize: 5.81GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 312.97GiB/s
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428888: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428905: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428912: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428918: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428924: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428933: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428939: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428945: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2022-07-25 16:22:35.428979: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:22:35.429082: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:22:35.429155: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2022-07-25 16:22:35.429175: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1

===> This is taking some time

2022-07-25 16:24:58.339299: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2022-07-25 16:24:58.339337: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2022-07-25 16:24:58.339345: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2022-07-25 16:24:58.339629: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:24:58.339885: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:24:58.340093: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2022-07-25 16:24:58.340267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 4774 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
>>>
```

I tried to first create a list of layers and add that list as a parameter to Sequential, but that did not help. In all cases creating a sequential model takes minutes. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you're using a CUDA version that was not intended to be used with your cc8.6 3060 GPU.  Upgrading to latest TF and whatever CUDA 11.x version it uses will help.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I just installed the anaconda packages which installs the old versions. Installing via pip solved the problem. Tensorflow/keras at 2.9.1/2.9.0 and cuda at 11.6.